# how do I deploy web app that use database

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am having difficulties deploying my ASP.NET Boilerplate template to my local machine. I can't decide which project to publish or whether I should reconfigure my web.config file in the output folder.

Comment: is your project MVC?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If your question is too open-ended, you aren't likely to get much help.  You'd benefit from showing us what you have done so far or at least providing a more detailed description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

***module-zero-core-template***

- **jQuery**: deploy xxx.xxx.Web.Mcv project
- **Angular/React/Vue**: deploy xxx.xxx.Web.Host project and the relevant frontend (Angular/React/Vue project)

***module-zero-core-template***

- **jQuery**: deploy xxx.xxx.WebMpa project
- **AngularJs**: deploy xxx.xxx.WebSpaAngular